# Trouble importing a directx file into blender

Tags: import, directx

I am using blender 2.6 and want to import a x. file using the io_directx_bel - addon. I have placed the script in the addons folder of blender.
However upon trying to import a .x file I get the following error:[image]

I hope you can help me out to resolve the error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Quite simply, the `bmesh` module is not available in 2.60**

The issue of the error is the missing `bmesh` module.  Link to 2.60 API confirms that it didn't exist back then

https://docs.blender.org/api/2.60/#standalone-modules

it begins to appear circa 2.63

https://docs.blender.org/api/2.63/#standalone-modules

Look to see the version number recommended for the addon.

This one requires at least 2.63

[https://github.com/limemidolin/directX_blender/blob/master/io_directx_bel/**init**.py#L7](https://github.com/limemidolin/directX_blender/blob/master/io_directx_bel/__init__.py#L7)

And >= 2.66 for

[https://github.com/poikilos/io_import_x/blob/master/**init**.py#L9](https://github.com/poikilos/io_import_x/blob/master/__init__.py#L9)

Comment: Ok, thanks for your replie. I have downloaded the last version you mentioned of the addon. The problem now is that I can import some .x files but I cannot import others. When trying to import them nothing happens.

Comment: Ok, I think I found out why: The importer only supports text encoded .x files and no binary .x files.